# getView() method of Array adapter class does not get called

Tags: android

In my custom Array adapter class getView() callback does not get call. 
I have checked too many question related to this around internet and this size too but I have not found any solution yet. 
Here is my AdapterClass

```
class HistoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RefelModal>{

    public HistoryAdapter(List<RefelModal> items) {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.view_refel_history_row,items);
        System.out.println("Call hits");
        System.out.println("And item list size ======"+items.size());
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        UrduTextView sno,familyPlanning,disease,healthCenter,date,doctor;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("getView callback hit");
        RefelModal item = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(view == null){
            System.out.println("getView callback hit and view is null");
            view = root.findViewById(R.layout.view_refel_history_row);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.sno = (UrduTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sno);
            holder.familyPlanning = (UrduTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.familyPlanning);
            holder.disease = (UrduTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disease);
            holder.healthCenter = (UrduTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.healthCenter);
            holder.date = (UrduTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.doctor = (UrduTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doctor);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.sno.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        holder.familyPlanning.setText(item.getFamilyPlanning().getName());
        holder.disease.setText(item.getDisease().getName());
        holder.healthCenter.setText(item.getHealthCenter().getName());
        holder.date.setText(Helper.FormatDate(item.getHealthCenterDate()));
        holder.doctor.setText(item.getHealthCenterDoctor().getName());

        return view;
    }

}
```

and in initControl() i am setting adapter as below

```
 ListView selected = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.selected);
    selected.setAdapter(selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter(Constants.getDatabase(getActivity()).getSelectedReferal(MemberDetailActivity.MEMBER_ID)));
```

any solution for my issue please

Comment: override getCount() and return the size.

Comment: @ADM size of what dear

Comment: like this...@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

Comment: The `List` is passed in the `super` constructor call. They don't need to override `getCount()`. `ArrayAdapter` will handle it. Are you certain the `ListView` is visible onscreen?

Comment: @MikeM. yes it is

Comment: Well, if you're certain you've called `setAdapter()` correctly, and `items.size()` is returning something >0, then that's about the only other thing it could be.

Comment: @MikeM. I too think so but really exhausted

Comment: Finally redesigned complete view from scratch and now able to view data thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the count of items .

```
    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
class HistoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RefelModal>{
ArrayAdapter<RefelModal> items;
    public HistoryAdapter(List<RefelModal> items) {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.view_refel_history_row,items);
this.items = items;
        System.out.println("Call hits");
        System.out.println("And item list size ======"+items.size());
    }
```

Comment: Please check out this link... https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

Comment: I do not think that I can directly assign a list to an Array Adapter